# Quicksort ArrayList<MyObject> with multiple of the same Values (myObject.getId()) isn't sorting completely

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, quicksort

I've got a quicksort algorithm to sort my ArrayLists. Since I'm working with ArrayLists instead of Arrays, I had to modify / add some parts of code compared to [the traditional way](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsQuicksort/article.html).

Everything works as intended except for one small thing: **The ArrayList isn't sorted correctly when I have multiple Objects with the same sorting-Value.**

So, first of all, here is my code:

```
public class Sort
{
    ... // Other sorting classes that always have an unique sorting-value anyway, so are working fine

    // The following sorting class can have double sorting-values, and here the sorting goes wrong
    public static class OPI{
        public static ArrayList<OrderedProductItem> opisByProductId;
        public static void sortOrderedProductItems(ArrayList<OrderedProductItem> orderedProductItems){
            opisByProductId = new ArrayList<OrderedProductItem>();

            if(orderedProductItems != null && orderedProductItems.size() > 0){
                // Since Java automatically creates a pointer behind the scenes,
                // we need to make a new ArrayList and fill them with the values
                for(OrderedProductItem opi : orderedProductItems)
                    opisByProductId.add(opi);

                quicksortOpisByProductId(0, opisByProductId.size() - 1);
            }
        }
        private static void quicksortOpisByProductId(int low, int high){
            int i = low, j = high;
            // Get the middle element from the middle of the list
            int middle = opisByProductId.get(low + (high - low) / 2).getProductId();

            // Divide into two lists
            while(i <= j){
                // If the current value from the left list is smaller than the middle
                // element, then get the next element from the left list
                while(opisByProductId.get(i).getProductId() < middle){
                    i++;
                    if(i > j){
                        i = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // If the current value from the right list is larger than the middle
                // element, then get the next element from the right list
                while(opisByProductId.get(j).getProductId() > middle){
                    j--;
                    if(j < i){
                        j = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // If we have found a value in the left list which is larger than
                // the middle element and if we have found a value in the right list
                // which is smaller than the middle element, then we exchange the values
                // PS: It might happen that the same values swap places
                if(i < j){
                    OrderedProductItem temp = opisByProductId.get(i);
                    opisByProductId.set(i, opisByProductId.get(j));
                    opisByProductId.set(j, temp);
                }

                if(i <= j){
                    i++;
                    j--;
                }
            }
            // Recursion
            if(low < j)
                quicksortOpisByProductId(low, j);
            if(i < high)
                quicksortOpisByProductId(i, high);
        }
    }
}
```

Example List:

Before the sorting algorithm:

```
position        ProductId
0               12
1               12
2               54
3               54
4               12
5               4
6               4
7               4
```

After the sorting algorithm:

```
position        ProductId
0               4
1               4
2               12
3               12
4               12
5               4
6               54
7               54
```

Comment: At a very quick glance, it seems to me you’re mixing array indices and `productId`s. For example, you’re choosing a pivot to be the `productId` of a middle list element, but then compare it to the array index `i` and `j`.

Comment: have you tried using sortedList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out my mistake. In the while-loops I had

```
// If the current value from the left list is smaller than the middle
// element, then get the next element from the left list
while(opisByProductId.get(i).getProductId() < middle){
    i++;
    if(i > j){
        i = j;
        break;
    }
}

// If the current value from the right list is larger than the middle
// element, then get the next element from the right list
while(opisByProductId.get(j).getProductId() > middle){
    j--;
    if(j < i){
        j = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Where I use the j and i in the if-statement. Instead I now use the following, fixing my issue:

```
// If the current value from the left list is smaller than the middle
// element, then get the next element from the left list
while(opisByProductId.get(i).getProductId() < middle){
    i++;
    if(i > high){ // <- high instead of j
        i = high; // <- high instead of j
        break;
    }
}

// If the current value from the right list is larger than the middle
// element, then get the next element from the right list
while(opisByProductId.get(j).getProductId() > middle){
    j--;
    if(j < low){ // <- low instead of i
        j = low; // <- low instead of i
        break;
    }
}
```

---

EDIT:

Created a UnitTest with @DaveP's test-data and it succeeded:

```
package business;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.Test;

import viewmodels.OrderedProductItem;

public class SUnitTest
{
    ... // Other UnitTests

    @Test
    public void testDoubleSorting(){
        // Arrange
        // Could be with any of them, but we do it with the OrderedProductItems,
        // since they can contain doubles
        ArrayList<OrderedProductItem> opis = new ArrayList<OrderedProductItem>();
        int[] unsortedIds = new int[]{
            12, 12, 54, 54, 12, 4, 4, 4, 7, 76, 45, 44, 1, 2, 34, 5, 4
        };
        // Sorted array of the exact same ID's for comparison
        int[] sortedIds = new int[]{
            1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 7, 12, 12, 12, 34, 44, 45, 54, 54, 76
        };
        for(int i = 0; i < unsortedIds.length; i++)
            // OrderedProductItem uses setProductId in its Constructor
            opis.add(new OrderedProductItem(unsortedIds[i]));

        // Invoke
        Sort.OPI.sortOrderedProductItems(opis);
        ArrayList<OrderedProductItem> resultOpis = Sort.OPI.opisByProductId;

        // Assert
        Assert.assertNotNull("resultOpis should not be null", resultOpis);
        Assert.assertEquals("resultOpis' size should equal the unsortedIds' size", unsortedIds.length, resultOpis.size());
        for(int i = 0; i < sortedIds.length; i++){
            Assert.assertNotNull("The OrderedProductItem at " + String.valueOf(i) + " should not be null", resultOpis.get(i));
            Assert.assertEquals("The OrderedProductItem's ProductId at " + String.valueOf(i) + " should be " + String.valueOf(sortedIds[i]), sortedIds[i], resultOpis.get(i).getProductId());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i Debugged your program and here what i found

Your High keeps going down never returned upward.

```
if(low < j)
    quicksortOpisByProductId(low, j);
if(i < high)
    quicksortOpisByProductId(i, high);
```

I changed this to

```
if(low < j)
    quicksortOpisByProductId(low, j);
if(i < high)
    quicksortOpisByProductId(i, opisByProductId.size() - 1);
```

And it works

Untouched your program changed the array 7 times

With this added it loops an additional 3 times taking it up to 10 times.

[Sorting Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1A89.png)

Comment: Hmm.. This kinda breaks quicksort.. Quicksort does the following: Looks at the middle value; divide the list into two equal parts and see in which of the two parts this middle value belongs. Then split that part in two again, etc. until it found it's correct position. With using the listsize again as high it doesn't split the higher list into two anymore.. So for example, with a List of 1000 it is first split into 2 x 500. Middle belongs in the top one, so it splits it into 2 x 250. Middle belongs in the bottom one this time, but instead of going from index 500-750, it goes from 500-1000 again

Comment: Yeah that one 4 was staying on the right hand side.. because of your High value never changing upward. So yeah. And i see in your fix. you got it. ERM

Your answer doesn't work still I put in more numbers and it didnt wort that correctly "1 5 2 4 4 4 4 7 12 12 12 44 34 45 54 54 76"

Comment: Hmm, my answer is working after I changed `j` and `i` into `high` and `low`. But for completeness I've used the test-data you gave in the comment above (`"1 5 2 4 4 4 4 7 12 12 12 44 34 45 54 54 76"`) and added an UnitTest to my answer. The UnitTest succeeded.

Comment: That was the output. The input was 12, 12, 54, 54, 12, 4, 4, 4, 7, 76, 45, 44, 1, 2, 34, 5, 4

Comment: I think there is either something wrong with your UnitTest or when you copied my code, because I now also tested it with that input and the UnitTest still succeeded.